# Search bar appears over welcome back message background

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

See below for a screenshot of the problem:

[image: Image of problem]

It's a little hard to see because there isn't much difference in colour/shade, but the search box appears above the light grey background of the welcome back message (but below the text).

Comment: Is it in front of the banner, or behind the banner, which has a little bit of transparency?

Comment: Ahh I see. Didn't notice the banner had transparency (just about barely see it now). That's probably why it looked like it was overlaid to me, when in fact it's just showing through. To me it still doesn't look right but if the consensus is it's fine then that's ok too.